# How do I determine if my integrated Intel graphics support "Shader Model 3"?

Tags: graphics, games, intel-graphics, steam

I am trying to play a Steam game on Ubuntu.  The game requires "Graphics: Shader model 3".

How do I determine if my integrated Intel graphics support Shader Model 3?

At present, when I launch the game, I hear the audio, but the screen is entirely black.

Running `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` yields:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.2.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 18.2.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I am not sure which (if any) of the above lines answer my question.

Comment: Run `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` and you'll see.

Comment: @Pilot6:  Thanks!  I have added the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` to my question, but I don't know how to interpret the results.

Comment: See `shading language version string: 1.30`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

`shading language version string` will show you version of shaders.

E.g.

```
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
```

Your system doesn't support shaders version 3.